# GitHub multiline suggestion with expanded context

Tags: github, diff, pull-request, github-flavored-markdown

It's possible to add a multiline code suggestion to a PR [like this](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-02-26-multi-line-code-suggestions-beta/), which is a really nice feature:

> You can now suggest a specific change to multiple lines of code when reviewing a pull request. To select a multi-line code block, you can either:
>
> - click and hold to the right of a line number, drag and then release the mouse when you’ve reached the last line of the desired selection; or
> - click on a line number, hold Shift, click on a second line numberv and click the "+" button to the right of the second line number.
>   Once you've selected the code block, click the diff icon and edit the text within the suggestion block.

But unfortunately this only works for selecting lines which are **within the default context**, which is shown in the PR.

I'd like to suggest a change which begins **some lines *before* the default diff context**. When looking at the diff I can easily click the "expand up" button (the little arrow) so that I can see an expanded diff.

[image: expand diff]

But I cannot "start" a suggestion in this expanded diff...
Trying to start the suggestion within the expanded white/non-yellow lines won't work. If I try to do this anyway, only a one-line suggestion is accepted.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Or is this just impossible?